# Estas palavras precisam de tradução

Tags: bug, tradução

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estes campos precisam de tradução

> Rooms 
>   users (61)
>   rooms (48)
>   Rooms
>   site
>   favorite
>   all
>   events
>   mine
>   invited
>   a list of rooms about
>   (more sites…)
>   created
>   people
>   event
>   active
>   Upcoming events:
>   tomorrow 
>   in 2 days 
>   Imported from a comment discussion on
>
> Quartos
>   usuários (61)
>   Quartos (48)
>   quartos
>   local
>   favorito
>   todos
>   eventos
>   meu
>   convidado
>   uma lista de quartos sobre
>   (mais sites ...)
>   criada
>   pessoas
>   evento
>   ativo
>   Próximos eventos:
>   amanhã
>   em 2 dias
>   Importado de uma discussão de comentário em

Comment: Vai no link [SOpt Translations ](https://pt.traducir.win/) (o unicórnio faz parte) e faça a sugestão de tradução.

Comment: @AugustoVasques como eu adiciono essas palavras lá?

Comment: Procura as strings com regex em Source Regex.

Comment: @AugustoVasques parece que as dessa página não existem

Comment: Exemplo: Clica no botão `with out tranlation` e use como entrada `*.room.*` vai vir https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=.%2Aroom.%2A&translationStatus=2 , na metade da lista  você vai encontrar https://pt.traducir.win/string/11618 que é a string `Open chat room`

Comment: Posso traduzir tudo o que lá está?

Comment: Fique a vontade, eu acabei de ver sua sugestão. Só um adendo, feita uma sugestão ela ainda vai tem que passar por aprovação.

Comment: E isso demora muito tempo? @AugustoVasques

Comment: Ai eu não sei, depende do dia. Se tiver gente para aprovar é rápido, mas final de semana tudo é mais demorado.

Comment: Estou quase certo que o "chat" não está no traducir, e ele é um site separado, por enquanto.